# Ogre GLSL light y-inverted

Tags: glsl, shader, ogre

I have a problem with my Ogre GLSL material lighting. I did everything according to the tutorials online but I can't seem to make my lighting code work properly.

It seems the only way to correct the lighting is to invert my `light_direction.y` however I do not believe that this is the correct way.  I have tried to multiply the `light_direction` with the `world_matrix` and with the `inverse_world_matrix` and the transposed versions of both but neither have helped.

The only thing that has helped is inverting the `light_direction.y`.

I have attached my code in the following files as well as screenshots of my app with inverted and non-inverted y.

My code:
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6eU_OZEVYlReE5HRXJ6eFNCZ0E/edit?usp=docslist_api) |
[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sua40sibqu4fjc6/mOgreBasic2.cpp?dl=0)

My ogre material:
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6eU_OZEVYlRYWRhcUJCLWRnVUk/edit?usp=docslist_api) | [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8xtbnca5bnr3ul/egglienShader.material?dl=0)

My vertex shader:
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6eU_OZEVYlRNkppaVFBODhhVG8/edit?usp=docslist_api) |
[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1yfjqir1n6vpsq/egglienShader_VS.glsl?dl=0)

My fragment shader:
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6eU_OZEVYlRVkFiYUVBdkJkSUk/edit?usp=docslist_api) |
[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i88n9h1cs5nr2z4/egglienShader_FS.glsl?dl=0)

Screenshot with non-inverted y:
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6eU_OZEVYlRV0w1a0RqOUtsdnc/edit?usp=docslist_api) |
[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6emwhmzis4yf0r/normal_y.png?dl=0)

Screenshot with y inverted:
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6eU_OZEVYlRd1I0VzAxSmo5MEE/edit?usp=docslist_api) |
[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj3dn5x8fq9l7sv/neg_y.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light vectors point from the object being lit to the light, so opposite the direction of the flow of light.

```
float _NdotL = max(dot(_normal, -_light_direction), 0.0);
```

[Phong Shading model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model)